# POM file is failing with http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to open a java maven project and I get this error in the pom file:

```
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution 
 will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
 resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

the pom goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>GID</groupId>
    <artifactId>AID</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>name</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jasper Report Specific Jars START -->
        <!-- to resolve itext maven issue -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>olap4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for report in xls format -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I understand that this is probably because another pom file that failed to be downloaded....but I am not able to figure how to resolve this problem

Comment: Right Click Project->Maven->Update Project

Comment: did so, still same error.

Comment: Try solution 2 mention in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**The issue is with SSL Certificate not added in Java keystore**

Try the below:

**Step 1)** Download Maven's SSL certificate as shown in the image below

[image: Export Maven Certificate]

**Step 2)** Figure out the Java used by Maven (Let's say your JDK location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_75).

Open a Command Prompt with Admin Privileges and navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\security".

Type in command `keytool -importcert -file "c:\Maven.cer" -alias "Maven"`, Default Java keystore password is "changeit".

You will be asked if you want to trust this certificate, Enter "Y" and hit enter.

[image: Keytool Import Certificate]

And you are good to download your repositories now...

You can run maven with -U argument to force it to check for the repositories from central maven repo.

Comment: Excellent explanation step by step. But maybe the user uses securised url while he doesn't need it.

Comment: Hi David,
True, but sometimes it depends on the user and the organization he belongs to...
Another option for user can to go with non-secure protocol i.e. using http instead of https, which may not require the above steps but may be  prone to various cyber vulnerabilities...

Answer (score 1):

You use the SSL version of the M2 central repository :

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
```

If you don't have any reason to use it, change your settings.xml to use the no SSL version of the repository :

```
  <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://repo.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
```

I notice that it is the the same thing for the Spring repository you declare :

replace `https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot`
 by `http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot`

Otherwise if you stay in HTTPS, your Maven commands have to rely on a JDK/JRE which contains the matching certificates.

Answer (score 0):

The error says `...resolution 
 will not be reattempted until the update interval of central...`. So you have to by force update your maven project.

Solution 1:

> Right Click Project->Maven->Update Project

Solution 2:

> Go to .m2 folder inside your Users->{YourUsername} folder
>
> In the search box type `.lastmodified`
>
> Delete the files which come after searching.
>
> Then go to your project pom.XML file and delete one character and type it again.
>
> Then save pom.xml file it will update.

Hope it helps.